# Substituting lines of a text file into bash commands

Tags: bash, curl

I want to run a bash command once for each line of a text file.

If I do:

```
while read l; do 
  echo $l; 
done < myfile.txt
```

I get each line echoed.

But when I use my actual command:

```
while read l; do 
  curl -X POST http://somedomain -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d $l
done < myfile.txt
```

I get errors. I think it may have something to do with escaping characters in the text file, but nothing I have tried works. What is the proper way to run a curl expression once for each line of a text file?

Comment: Please post **relevant** error messages verbatim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use quotes.

```
foocmd ... "$l"
```

Comment: thanks. Also had to remove 's from my text file. So ultimately, when substituting a variable use " in place of '.